# Rails3 + Cucumber + Factory_girl_rails + Authlogic issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, authlogic, factory-bot

I've been struggling with this all day long!

In the GemFile, I have:

```
group :test do
    gem 'database_cleaner'
    gem 'cucumber-rails'
    gem 'cucumber'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'spork'
    gem 'launchy'
    gem 'capybara' 
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

In my login.feature I have:

```
Feature: Login on my web site
  In order manage my account details
  As a security enthusiast
  I want to be able, to login and logout and view the superadmin button only when authorized

  Scenario: Check if login is working
    Given the following user records
      | email            | password |
      | julien@gmail.com | password |
      | bob@hotmail.com  | password |
    And I have 2 or more user records
    When I go to the login_url
    And I fill in "user_session_email" with "julien@gmail.com"
    And I fill in "user_session_password" with "password"
    And I press "Login"
    Then show me the page
    Then I should see "Logged in."
```

And Finally in my logins_steps.rb file:

```
Given /^the following user records$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |hash|
    u = Factory(:user, hash)
  end
end
```

Everything is working well when I do it by hand, but when I run **rake cucumber**, The fields are filled out, the button is pressed and I'm redirected to the home page like it should, but the problem is that I'm not logged in, nor do I see any flash message (it should say logged in)

If I try to login with a wrong password, I do get redirected to the login page ...

I have no idea where this issue comes from, I've tried to play around with the **include Authlogic::TestCase**  and **require "authlogic/test_case"** but none of them are working.

Is it a cookie, authlogic, factory_girl or cucumber issue, I really have no clue.

If any one has an idea, please feel free to leave me a message!

Cheers,
Julien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,
found the answer,
you have to setup the default host (which is set to www.example.com) to your domain.

```
Capybara.default_host = "www.website.local"
Capybara.server_port = 3000
```